# Undeploy functions in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have deployed one function as part of Firebase deploy command and I could see the same in Firebase/Google Cloud console.Is there any way to remove the same functions, as directly removing the functions folder and deploying it again is not actually removing the already deployed functions.

Also I tried disabling the hosting as well, but that also didn't help.
Could someone please let us know if there is any command to *un-deploy* the already deployed functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using firebase itself, the only way I am aware of is to deploy an empty/do-nothing function, which will overwrite your existing function(s).

You could also do this from the Google cloud functions console. Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=my-project, find the function you want to delete, click on the three vertical dots at the right, and choose "Delete".

[image]

Comment: Note: The console method doesn't work unless you are using the same project in both google and firebase.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that deleting is the same as un-deploying?

If so, I have used the command **firebase functions:delete myFunc** to delete a function named myFunc.

Additional information is available here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#delete_functions

In the firebase console, on the functions page, there is an icon on the far right you can click to see a menu for deleting items.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the function to an empty block and run the deploy command:

```
exports.myFunc = {}
```

This will delete the function:

```
$ firebase deploy
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: deleting function myFunc...
✔  functions[myFunc]: Successful delete operation.
```